# No deserializer defined for array type

Tags: java, web-services, soap, consumer

I'm trying to consume webservice and faced up with issue. I've imported WSDL file and got Java classes generated. I can connect to webservice, however when I ask for data I get such error.

WSDL File: https://www.geckobooking.dk/api7/webservice.php?WSDL

**Client code**

```
    GeckobookingServiceLocator service = new GeckobookingServiceLocator();
    service.setMaintainSession(true);
    GeckobookingPortType port = service.getgeckobookingPort();
    boolean connect = port.connect(new BigInteger("xxxx"), "name", "secretKey");
    System.out.println("Connect status:" + connect); // that works fine, return true.
    // issue happens in that line
    CustomerHandles customer_GetAll = port.customer_GetAll();
```

**customer_GetAll**

Issue happens on this line:

> java.lang.Object _resp = _call.invoke(new java.lang.Object[] {});

Here is a whole method

```
   public geckobooking_pkg.CustomerHandles customer_GetAll() throws java.rmi.RemoteException {
        if (super.cachedEndpoint == null) {
            throw new org.apache.axis.NoEndPointException();
        }
        org.apache.axis.client.Call _call = createCall();
        _call.setOperation(_operations[14]);
        _call.setUseSOAPAction(true);
        _call.setSOAPActionURI("urn:geckobookingAction");
        _call.setSOAPVersion(org.apache.axis.soap.SOAPConstants.SOAP11_CONSTANTS);
        _call.setOperationName(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("urn:geckobooking", "Customer_GetAll"));

        setRequestHeaders(_call);
        setAttachments(_call);
        try { 
            java.lang.Object _resp = _call.invoke(new java.lang.Object[] {});
            if (_resp instanceof java.rmi.RemoteException) {
                throw (java.rmi.RemoteException)_resp;
            }
            else {
                extractAttachments(_call);
                try {
                    return (geckobooking_pkg.CustomerHandles) _resp;
                } catch (java.lang.Exception _exception) {
                    return (geckobooking_pkg.CustomerHandles) org.apache.axis.utils.JavaUtils.convert(_resp, geckobooking_pkg.CustomerHandles.class);
                }
            }
        } catch (org.apache.axis.AxisFault axisFaultException) {
            throw axisFaultException;
        }
    }
```

**Error** (when use auto-generated classes)

```
org.xml.sax.SAXException: No deserializer defined for array type {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/}Struct
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.ArrayDeserializer.onStartElement(ArrayDeserializer.java:276)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializerImpl.startElement(DeserializerImpl.java:393)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.startElement(DeserializationContext.java:1048)
    at org.apache.axis.message.SAX2EventRecorder.replay(SAX2EventRecorder.java:165)
    at org.apache.axis.message.MessageElement.publishToHandler(MessageElement.java:1141)
    at org.apache.axis.message.RPCElement.deserialize(RPCElement.java:345)
    at org.apache.axis.message.RPCElement.getParams(RPCElement.java:384)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2467)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
    at geckobooking_pkg.GeckobookingBindingStub.customer_GetAll(GeckobookingBindingStub.java:1420)
    at geckobooking.SOAPClientSAAJ.auto(SOAPClientSAAJ.java:24)
    at geckobooking.SOAPClientSAAJ.main(SOAPClientSAAJ.java:11)
```

I kind of understand what is the issue, however I have no clue how to resolve it.

Here is an response I get if I use SOAPMessage approach (when I build messages myself)

**Real response**

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="urn:geckobooking" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:Customer_GetAllResponse>
      <Customer_GetAllReturn xsi:type="ns1:CustomerHandles">
        <CustomerHandles SOAP-ENC:arrayType="SOAP-ENC:Struct[5003]" xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array">
          <item xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Struct"><Id xsi:type="xsd:string">121</Id></item>
          <item xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Struct"><Id xsi:type="xsd:string">122</Id></item>
          <item xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Struct"><Id xsi:type="xsd:string">123</Id></item>
          <item xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Struct"><Id xsi:type="xsd:string">124</Id></item>
          <item xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Struct"><Id xsi:type="xsd:string">125</Id></item>
        </CustomerHandles>
      </Customer_GetAllReturn>
    </ns1:Customer_GetAllResponse>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Definition of CustomerHandles class

```
/**
 * CustomerHandles.java
 *
 * This file was auto-generated from WSDL
 * by the Apache Axis 1.4 Apr 22, 2006 (06:55:48 PDT) WSDL2Java emitter.
 */

package geckobooking_pkg;

public class CustomerHandles  implements java.io.Serializable {

private java.lang.Object customerHandles;

public CustomerHandles() {
}

public CustomerHandles(
       java.lang.Object customerHandles) {
       this.customerHandles = customerHandles;
}


/**
 * Gets the customerHandles value for this CustomerHandles.
 * 
 * @return customerHandles
 */
public java.lang.Object getCustomerHandles() {
    return customerHandles;
}


/**
 * Sets the customerHandles value for this CustomerHandles.
 * 
 * @param customerHandles
 */
public void setCustomerHandles(java.lang.Object customerHandles) {
    this.customerHandles = customerHandles;
}

private java.lang.Object __equalsCalc = null;
public synchronized boolean equals(java.lang.Object obj) {
    if (!(obj instanceof CustomerHandles)) return false;
    CustomerHandles other = (CustomerHandles) obj;
    if (obj == null) return false;
    if (this == obj) return true;
    if (__equalsCalc != null) {
        return (__equalsCalc == obj);
    }
    __equalsCalc = obj;
    boolean _equals;
    _equals = true && 
        ((this.customerHandles==null && other.getCustomerHandles()==null) || 
         (this.customerHandles!=null &&
          this.customerHandles.equals(other.getCustomerHandles())));
    __equalsCalc = null;
    return _equals;
}

private boolean __hashCodeCalc = false;
public synchronized int hashCode() {
    if (__hashCodeCalc) {
        return 0;
    }
    __hashCodeCalc = true;
    int _hashCode = 1;
    if (getCustomerHandles() != null) {
        _hashCode += getCustomerHandles().hashCode();
    }
    __hashCodeCalc = false;
    return _hashCode;
}

// Type metadata
private static org.apache.axis.description.TypeDesc typeDesc =
    new org.apache.axis.description.TypeDesc(CustomerHandles.class, true);

static {
    typeDesc.setXmlType(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("urn:geckobooking", "CustomerHandles"));
    org.apache.axis.description.ElementDesc elemField = new org.apache.axis.description.ElementDesc();
    elemField.setFieldName("customerHandles");
    elemField.setXmlName(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("", "CustomerHandles"));
    elemField.setXmlType(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema", "anyType"));
    elemField.setNillable(false);
    typeDesc.addFieldDesc(elemField);
}

/**
 * Return type metadata object
 */
public static org.apache.axis.description.TypeDesc getTypeDesc() {
    return typeDesc;
}

/**
 * Get Custom Serializer
 */
public static org.apache.axis.encoding.Serializer getSerializer(
       java.lang.String mechType, 
       java.lang.Class _javaType,  
       javax.xml.namespace.QName _xmlType) {
    return 
      new  org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.BeanSerializer(
        _javaType, _xmlType, typeDesc);
}

/**
 * Get Custom Deserializer
 */
public static org.apache.axis.encoding.Deserializer getDeserializer(
       java.lang.String mechType, 
       java.lang.Class _javaType,  
       javax.xml.namespace.QName _xmlType) {
    return 
      new  org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.BeanDeserializer(
        _javaType, _xmlType, typeDesc);
}
```

}

I would much appreciate any assist with this issue.

Comment: I think, you need to paste your client code too. Also, it looks server side issue not yours. There might be some tweaking done in generated code to get rid of error message but that wouldn't mean that server side is not flawed.

Comment: @SabirKhan: thanks for answer, I've added WSDL source and client-code.

Comment: Are you able to find `CustomerHandles` definition in generated code? Most likely solution is to change that definition.

Comment: @SabirKhan yes, it is present. I've added it to question.

Answer (score 1):

In `CustomerHandles` generated class code, Could you please try replacing `"urn:geckobooking` by empty String `""` in `typeDesc.setXmlType(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("urn:geckobooking", "CustomerHandles"));`?

i.e. try running webservice call with `typeDesc.setXmlType(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("", "CustomerHandles"));`

Obviously, above suggestion didn't worked for you - that was based on my recall of few years that something similar had worked for me.

I guess, there is a need to define your own **Serializer** and **Deserializer** for custom array objects that you are trying to send and receive via the wire ( **in Axis WSDD file**). [Difference between wsdd and wsdl](http://www.coderanch.com/t/149035/java-Web-Services-SCDJWS/certification/Difference-wsdd-wsdl).

Refer Section **"When Beans Are Not Enough - Custom Serialization"** in [What_Axis_can_not_send_via_SOAP](http://axis.apache.org/axis/java/user-guide.html#What_Axis_can_not_send_via_SOAP)  about using `<typeMapping />` to define your own serializer and deserializer for custom array types.  if you are not the one who developed the said web service, I think you need to inform web service team about this issue as stack trace says that default - `ArrayDeserializer` is not sufficient for your array object.

Comment: thanks, I informed owner of web-service, and if they confirm/fix issue I will accept it as an answer.

Comment: sure, glad to be of some help . Hope it gets sorted out.